# Texture size of Social.localUser.image

Tags: unity-game-engine, textures, game-center

Im having a hard time figuring out the actual size of the `texture2D` that gets returned from `Social.localUser.image`.  When I try to read its width and height it comes back with a 6x4 which doesn't sound right at all.  Possibly I'm doing it wrong, or there is a doc that says the size it returns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if anyone else is looking for the solution its 512x512.

Answer (score 0):

From The Link:
https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity/issues/474

Here someone checked the URL of the Texture and He got 96 pixels.

I also checked, it's not 512 x 512.

It is 96 pixels.